# How to display fields from parent model at my custom module view?

Tags: odoo-13

myview.xml

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record model = "ir.ui.view" id = "custom_expense.list">
      <field name = "name"> custom_expense list </field>
      <field name = "model"> custom_expense.custom_expense </field>
      <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
        <tree>
          <field name = "name" />
          <field name = "test" />
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record model = "ir.actions.act_window" id = "custom_expense.action_window">
      <field name = "name"> custom_expense </field>
      <field name = "res_model"> custom_expense.custom_expense </field>
      <field name = "view_mode"> tree, form </field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name = "custom_expense" id = "custom_expense.menu_root" />
    <menuitem name = "Menu 1" id = "custom_expense.menu_1" parent = "custom_expense.menu_root" />
    <menuitem name = "Submenu 1" id = "custom_expense.menu_1_list" parent = "custom_expense.menu_1"

              action = "custom_expense.action_window" />
  </data>
</odoo>
```

mymodel.py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
class custom_expense (models.Model):
    _name = 'custom_expense.custom_expense'
    _inherit = 'hr.expense'

    test = fields.Char (string = 'Valuethird')
```

I would like to display "name" field from hr.expense model but I found error:    TypeError: Many2many fields custom_expense.custom_expense.tax_ids and hr.expense.tax_ids use the same table and columns - - -

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add a new field to hr.expense. If thats the case you dont need to create new model. only the _inherit will be enough  and no need of _name in python file and just inherit the xml file. If you want the new table, then you will need to redefine the many2many in the parent model.

Comment: No, I don't want to add a new field to hr.expense. I thought if I inherit hr.expense model I can use any fields from parent model(hr.expense) and display those fields to my custom module.

Comment: then what you have done is okey.but you need to redefine the m2m fields as the tables will be already using for hr.expense